# Is there a way to send data from client to server in angular universal?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

We are using angular 5.2.8 with nguniversal/express-engine 5.0.0-beta.6 and we are using external payment services. The payment system requires a form to be posted to their URL and has an input for callbackURL.

The callback from that request sends us back a POST request with data. We need to post that data to our backend with user credentials. In angular we can't receive post requests.

I have tried some options for the solution but none of them worked so far:

- Listening for posts in express and then transfer data to angular
- Trying to send cookies or user information to server for making a server to server request to our backend.

I need to either send the contents of the callback post to client side, or pass user credentials to server side.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach should work. To be really generic, you could provide the express request toyour angular universal app, so that components/services needed the request's values can access it

**server.ts**

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {


  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.path,
    extraProviders: [
      {
        provide: 'httpRequest',
        useValue: options.req,

      }
    ]
  }).then(html => {

    callback(null, html);
  });
});

//Handle your post
app.post('/yourpostUrl', (req, res) => {

  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), {req});
});
```

Then provide the request angular side. Don't forget to make it as Optional so that it does not thrown an error client side

**component.ts**

```
 constructor(@Optional() @Inject('httpRequest') private httpRequest: any)
  {
      //here you can use httpRequest's valuesy
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I couldn't use this solution on our project, could not get a httpRequest object, I assume its because of authentication flow and authGuards. But we solved the issue by catching the post in server-side and after calling another service in client-side to check if everything is working properly.

Comment: @David do you know if it's possible to use redis in an angular component? server side? E.g. pass a tree of GUIDs used in api calls during rendering back to express, so that in future express can handle cache invalidation?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737200/access-redis-connection-in-angular-component-universal-ssr

Answer (score 0):

In an Angular Universal project, in the server.ts file, we write the following kind of code.

So, basically, we are redirecting the browser to the index.html for all the Angular routes. However, the URLs starting with `/api/*` are excluded as they below to the APIs. It seems you need to have the callback URL starting with `/api/*` and that's where you need to have an HTTP POST API to handle the call.

```
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {

});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am handling like app.post('/someUrl') in the server side and I can read res.body but I need a way to send it to Angular.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I got it wrong then. I don't have a ready made answer for now. Can service worker help here? Need to check...