# Is there a way to access a variable from interceptor.service.ts in server.ts file in angular 6 universal?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I need to access the "this.cacheFlag" variable from interceptor.service.ts into server.ts file at the root in my application.

```js
return next.handle(this.authReq).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.reqArray.push(event.status);
        this.cacheFlag = true; //this is the variable I want to access in server.ts file

      }
    }),
    catchError((error, caught) => {
      //intercept the response error and displace it to the console
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if(error.url.indexOf("detail?referenceCode=") == -1){
          this.reqArray.push(error.status);
          this.cacheFlag = false; //this is the variable I want to access in server.ts file
        }
   })
```

Comment: how about adding a shared service that is injected into both interceptor.service.ts and server.ts and setting the flag inside the shared service?

Comment: The interceptor itself is a service. The problem is server.ts file is at the root level (i.e myapp/server.ts) and all the services (including the common ones) are inside (myapp/src/app/interceptor.service.ts).

Comment: Is server.ts an angular component ? anything special about the component ? Are server.ts and interceptor sharing the same module?

Comment: You can provide an object from the server and modify its properties from your interceptor. You could do it with the response object like here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669873/1160794

Answer (score 1):

try using a shared service and then subscribing to the value in your server.ts for example 
create a shared service with this code

```
cacheFlag = new Observable<boolean>(false);
_cacheFlag = this.cacheFlag.asObservable();


nextValue(val) {
  this.cacheFlag.next(val);
}
```

and then in the constructor of your interceptor.ts and server.ts add this as well as a variable to assign the value being subscribed to from your shared service

```
cf: boolean;

constructor( private ss: SharedService ) {
   ss._cacheFlag.subscribe(value => this.cf = value)
}
```

and then finally in your interceptor.ts

```
return next.handle(this.authReq).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.reqArray.push(event.status);
        this.ss.nextValue(true); //change this part

      }
    }),
    catchError((error, caught) => {
      //intercept the response error and displace it to the console
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if(error.url.indexOf("detail?referenceCode=") == -1){
          this.reqArray.push(error.status);
          this.ss.nextValue(false) //change this part
        }
   })
```

the value will change in both your interceptor.ts and your server.ts
I hope that helped in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable static :

```
export class MyInterceptorService {
  static cacheFlag;

  intercept(...) {
    ...
    if (MyInterceptorService.cacheFlag) {
      // Cache
    }
  }
}
```